# How do I build a Hyper-V enabled kernel in a Ubuntu 12.10 guest VM on Server 2012?

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, hyper-v

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 x64 as guest VM on Server 2012, and want to upgrade kernel to Linux 3.8, as the 3.8 kernel supports the balloon driver for dynamic memory and new IC (I assume).

Before upgrading, the mouse working was working; after upgrading to a generic 3.8 kernel the mouse doesn't work and no **hv_timesource, hv_ballon** driver is present.

I've tried to install the kernel from source enabling all hyper-v components with no luck. I've installed a 3.8 kernel with hyper-v support from v.s.cz/linuxhyperv.php but still want to compile my own custom kernel with Ubuntu patches.

The VM is configured with 2 virtual CPUs. CPU 2 is always under 100% load! Does not support SMP?

Therefore my questions are:

1. How to enable Hyper-V modules? And, if this requires a custom build, then
2. How to install kernel 3.8 from source on Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Rarring:

```
sudo sed -i 's/quantal/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

[How to upgrade to Ringtail daily build?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082861)

But hv_balloon was disabled

To enable it run:

```
sudo modprobe hv_baloon
```

All modules working now:

```
hmh@userv1:~$ lsmod | grep hv
hv_balloon             17229  0
hv_storvsc             17495  2
hv_netvsc              22768  0
hv_utils               13568  0
hv_vmbus               34431  5 hv_balloon,hv_netvsc,hid_hyperv,hv_utils,hv_storvsc
```

Mouse also working:

```
hmh@userv1:~$ lsmod | grep hid
hid_generic            12540  0
hid_hyperv             13059  0
hid                   101002  2 hid_hyperv,hid_generic
mac_hid                13205  0
hv_vmbus               34431  5 hv_balloon,hv_netvsc,hid_hyperv,hv_utils,hv_storvsc
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 has LIS (Linux Integrated Services) 3.1 . This is  the same in 12.04 and is limited. MS relased 3.4 last automn 2012 but works on RedHat and CentOS but not for Debian based OS (like Ubuntu).

Should be any genius programmer around to make LIS 3.4 to work with 12.04 and 12.10 ? Please Ô please !

Comment: My question was about compiling custom kernel with all hyper-v drivers enabled!